# remove big object from a picture in open cv

Tags: python, opencv

Hi im trying to remove big object from a picture in openCV in python  I found a way to do it remove small and it worked perfectly.  How could I tweak the code to only keep object from a specific range of size.

Here [How to remove small connected objects using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42798659/how-to-remove-small-connected-objects-using-opencv)

But when I do it for big object I get this:

> error:OpenCV(3.4.1) Error: Assertion failed (iDepth == 0 || iDepth == 1) in cv::connectedComponents_sub1, file C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\connectedcomponents.cpp, line 3941 Traceback (most recent call last):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such an error states that there is some mismatch with the depth of the image. The function expects the input image to be 8 bit in depth. Convert your image using the following and then pass it to the function `cv2.connectedComponents()`:

```
img=img.astype(numpy.uint8)
```

Comment: I dont have enough rep to upvote but I acceped it, sorry im new to this site

Comment: @JérémiePerrault No problem. All the best!!