# Detecting boxes via Hough Transform

Tags: python, computer-vision, hough-transform, houghlinesp, houghlines

Using HoughTransform I am trying to detect boxes and provide for a distinct color.

So far my understanding is a box is horizontal and vertical line .

[image: Canny]

my code is

```
lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges,1,np.pi/180, 50) 

# The below for loop runs till r and theta values  
# are in the range of the 2d array 
for r,theta in lines[0]: 

# Stores the value of cos(theta) in a 
a = np.cos(theta) 

# Stores the value of sin(theta) in b 
b = np.sin(theta) 

# x0 stores the value rcos(theta) 
x0 = a*r 

# y0 stores the value rsin(theta) 
y0 = b*r 

# x1 stores the rounded off value of (rcos(theta)-1000sin(theta)) 
x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b)) 

# y1 stores the rounded off value of (rsin(theta)+1000cos(theta)) 
y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a)) 

# x2 stores the rounded off value of (rcos(theta)+1000sin(theta)) 
x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b)) 

# y2 stores the rounded off value of (rsin(theta)-1000cos(theta)) 
y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a)) 

# cv2.line draws a line in img from the point(x1,y1) to (x2,y2). 
# (255,255,255) denotes the colour of the line to be.  
cv2.line(img,(x1,y1), (x2,y2), (255,255,255),2) `
```

What could i do so that the boxes can be colored or identified?

Comment: Wouldn't be as exciting... but I am pretty certain you could do this way more easily with a blob tool since the boxes are cleanly isolated from one another

Comment: This would also be more robust for the K box which is likely going to give any hough lines implementation trouble.

Comment: I tried to find what is a blob tool.  I couldn't make any headway,  could you post some link.

Comment: connectedComponentsWithStats is the function that you want if you are going to try to do this with blobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do vertical and horizontal line detection separately so that you can make them each more specific.

Go through all your lines and compile a list of intersections between horizontal and vertical line combinations

Now you have a list of 2d points that if you draw them should pretty much be on the corners of the boxes.  The final step is to collect those points into meaningful sets.

To get those sets, I would start with the point nearest origin (just for the sake of starting somewhere).  I would look through all the other points for the closest *other* point that has a greater x but is withing +-5 (or some configurable range) y of the starting point. Then do the same but in the y direction.  You now have the bottom corner of the box.  Which you could just complete and start your ocr on, but to be more robust, find the final corner as well.

Once all 4 corners are found, remove all of those points from your intersection array and add however you want to denote box locations into a new array.  Rinse and repeat as now a different point will be nearest origin.  Without actually testing this, I think it will choke (or need some conditional improvement for missing walls) on the K box but should be pretty generic to variable box shapes and sizes.

Edit 1: In testing, I am finding that it will probably be difficult to separate the close corners of two adjacent boxes.  I think a more generic and robust solution would be to after you get collisions, do a point clustering operation at about 1/3 box min side length.  This will average corners together with their nearest neighbor.  So this will slightly change the strategy as you will need to use every corner twice (box to left and box to right) except for end points.

Wrote up some test code and it is functional, here are the outputs:
[image]

Code, sorry for c++ and not at all optimized, happy friday :)

```
//CPP libaries
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

//Included libraries
//Note: these headers have to be before any opencv due to a namespace collision (could probably be fixed)

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

using namespace cv;

// Finds the intersection of two lines, or returns false.
// The lines are defined by (o1, p1) and (o2, p2).
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446126/opencv-2d-line-intersection-helper-function
bool intersection(Point2f o1, Point2f p1, Point2f o2, Point2f p2,
    Point2f &r)
{
    Point2f x = o2 - o1;
    Point2f d1 = p1 - o1;
    Point2f d2 = p2 - o2;

    float cross = d1.x*d2.y - d1.y*d2.x;
    if (abs(cross) < /*EPS*/1e-8)
        return false;

    double t1 = (x.x * d2.y - x.y * d2.x) / cross;
    r = o1 + d1 * t1;
    return true;
}

std::vector<Point2f> clusterPts(std::vector<Point2f> inputPts, double clusterRadius_Squared)
{
    std::vector<Point2f> outputPts = std::vector<Point2f>();
    while(inputPts.size()>0)
    {
        Point2f clusterCenter = inputPts[0];
        while (true)
        {
            Point2f newClustCenter = Point2f(0, 0);
            int averagingCount = 0;
            std::vector<int> clusterIndicies = std::vector<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < inputPts.size(); i++)
            {
                if (clusterRadius_Squared >= pow(inputPts[i].x - clusterCenter.x, 2) + pow(inputPts[i].y - clusterCenter.y, 2))
                {
                    newClustCenter.x += inputPts[i].x;
                    newClustCenter.y += inputPts[i].y;
                    averagingCount += 1;
                    clusterIndicies.push_back(i);
                }
            }
            newClustCenter = newClustCenter / (double)averagingCount;

            if (newClustCenter == clusterCenter)
            {
                //remove all points inside cluster from inputPts, stash cluster center, and break inner while loop
                std::vector<Point2f> remainingPts = std::vector<Point2f>();
                for (int i = 0; i < inputPts.size(); i++)
                {
                    if (std::find(clusterIndicies.begin(), clusterIndicies.end(), i) == clusterIndicies.end())
                    {
                        remainingPts.push_back(inputPts[i]);
                    }
                }
                inputPts = remainingPts;
                outputPts.push_back(clusterCenter);
                break;
            }
            else
            { 
                clusterCenter = newClustCenter;
            }
        }
    }
    return outputPts;
}

std::vector<Rect> findBoxes(std::vector<Point2f> corners, bool shrinkBoxes = false, int boxSideLength_Guess = 50)
{
    std::vector<Rect> outBoxes = std::vector<Rect>();
    int approxBoxSize = 1000 * boxSideLength_Guess;

    while (corners.size()>4)
    {
        //find point above or below (these points will be removed from array after used)
        int secondPtIndex = -1;
        for (int i = 1; i < corners.size(); i++)
        {
            if (abs(corners[i].x - corners[0].x) < boxSideLength_Guess / 2.0)
            {
                secondPtIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (secondPtIndex == -1)
        {
            std::cout << "bad box point tossed" << std::endl;
            corners.erase(corners.begin() + 0);
            continue;
        }

        //now search for closest same level point on either side
        int thirdIndexRight = -1;
        int thirdIndexLeft = -1;
        double minDistRight = approxBoxSize;
        double minDistLeft = -approxBoxSize;
        for (int i = 2; i < corners.size(); i++)
        {
            if (abs(corners[i].y - corners[secondPtIndex].y) < boxSideLength_Guess / 2.0)
            {
                double dist = corners[i].x - corners[secondPtIndex].x;

                if (dist < 0 && dist > minDistLeft) //check left
                {
                    minDistLeft = dist;
                    thirdIndexLeft = i;
                }   
                else if(dist > 0 && dist < minDistRight) //check right
                {
                    minDistRight = dist;
                    thirdIndexRight = i;
                }
            }
        }

        if (thirdIndexLeft != -1) { approxBoxSize = 1.5 * abs(minDistLeft); }
        if (thirdIndexRight != -1) { approxBoxSize = 1.5 * minDistRight; }

        int fourthIndexRight = -1;
        int fourthIndexLeft = -1;

        for (int i = 1; i < corners.size(); i++)
        {
            if (i == thirdIndexLeft || i == thirdIndexRight) { continue; }

            if (thirdIndexLeft != -1 && abs(corners[i].x - corners[thirdIndexLeft].x) < boxSideLength_Guess / 2.0)
            { fourthIndexLeft = i; }
            if (thirdIndexRight != -1 && abs(corners[i].x - corners[thirdIndexRight].x) < boxSideLength_Guess / 2.0)
            { fourthIndexRight = i; }
        }

        if (!shrinkBoxes)
        {
            if (fourthIndexRight != -1)
            {
                outBoxes.push_back(Rect(corners[0], corners[thirdIndexRight]));
            }
            if (fourthIndexLeft != -1)
            {
                outBoxes.push_back(Rect(corners[0], corners[thirdIndexLeft]));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (fourthIndexRight != -1)
            {
                outBoxes.push_back(Rect(corners[0] * 0.90 + corners[thirdIndexRight] *0.10, corners[0] * 0.10 + corners[thirdIndexRight] * 0.90));
            }
            if (fourthIndexLeft != -1)
            {
                outBoxes.push_back(Rect(corners[0] * 0.90 + corners[thirdIndexLeft] * 0.10, corners[0] * 0.10 + corners[thirdIndexLeft] * 0.90));
            }
        }


        corners.erase(corners.begin() + secondPtIndex);
        corners.erase(corners.begin() + 0);
    }
    std::cout << approxBoxSize << std::endl;
    return outBoxes;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat image = imread("../../resources/images/boxPic.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    imshow("source", image);

    //namedWindow("Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);// Create a window for display.
    //imshow("Display window", image);                   // Show our image inside it.

    Mat edges, lineOverlay, cornerOverlay, finalBoxes;
    Canny(image, edges, 50, 200, 3);
    //edges = image;
    //cvtColor(image, edges, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
    cvtColor(image, lineOverlay, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
    cvtColor(image, cornerOverlay, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
    cvtColor(image, finalBoxes, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

    std::cout << image.cols << " , "<<image.rows << std::endl;

    std::vector<Vec2f> linesHorizontal;
    std::vector<Point> ptsLH;
    HoughLines(edges, linesHorizontal, 5, CV_PI / 180, 2 * edges.cols * 0.6, 0.0,0.0, CV_PI / 4, 3 * CV_PI / 4);

    std::vector<Vec2f> linesVertical;
    std::vector<Point> ptsLV;
    HoughLines(edges, linesVertical, 5, CV_PI / 180, 2 * edges.rows * 0.6,0,0,-CV_PI/32,CV_PI/32);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < linesHorizontal.size(); i++)
    {
        float rho = linesHorizontal[i][0], theta = linesHorizontal[i][1];
        Point pt1, pt2;
        double a = cos(theta), b = sin(theta);
        double x0 = a * rho, y0 = b * rho;
        pt1.x = cvRound(x0 + 1000 * (-b));
        pt1.y = cvRound(y0 + 1000 * (a));
        pt2.x = cvRound(x0 - 1000 * (-b));
        pt2.y = cvRound(y0 - 1000 * (a));
        ptsLH.push_back(pt1);
        ptsLH.push_back(pt2);
        line(lineOverlay, pt1, pt2, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 1, LINE_AA);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < linesVertical.size(); i++)
    {
        float rho = linesVertical[i][0], theta = linesVertical[i][1];
        Point pt1, pt2;
        double a = cos(theta), b = sin(theta);
        double x0 = a * rho, y0 = b * rho;
        pt1.x = cvRound(x0 + 1000 * (-b));
        pt1.y = cvRound(y0 + 1000 * (a));
        pt2.x = cvRound(x0 - 1000 * (-b));
        pt2.y = cvRound(y0 - 1000 * (a));
        ptsLV.push_back(pt1);
        ptsLV.push_back(pt2);
        line(lineOverlay, pt1, pt2, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1, LINE_AA);
    }

    imshow("edged", edges);
    imshow("detected lines", lineOverlay);

    //look for collisions
    std::vector<Point2f> xPts;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < linesHorizontal.size(); i++)
    {
        for (size_t ii = 0; ii < linesVertical.size(); ii++)
        {
            Point2f xPt;
            bool intersectionExists = intersection(ptsLH[2 * i], ptsLH[2 * i + 1], ptsLV[2 * ii], ptsLV[2 * ii + 1], xPt);
            if (intersectionExists)
            {
                xPts.push_back(xPt);
            }
        }
    }
    waitKey(1000);
    std::vector<Point2f> boxCorners = clusterPts(xPts, 25*25);
    for (int i = 0; i < boxCorners.size(); i++)
    {
        circle(cornerOverlay, boxCorners[i], 5, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
    }
    imshow("detected corners", cornerOverlay);

    //group make boxes for groups of points
    std::vector<Rect> ocrBoxes = findBoxes(boxCorners,true);
    for (int i = 0; i < ocrBoxes.size(); i++)
    {
        if (i % 3 == 0) { rectangle(finalBoxes, ocrBoxes[i], Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2); }
        else if(i % 3 == 1) { rectangle(finalBoxes, ocrBoxes[i], Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2); }
        else if (i % 3 == 2) { rectangle(finalBoxes, ocrBoxes[i], Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2); }
    }

    imshow("detected boxes", finalBoxes);

    waitKey(0);                                          // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This would work for me if  I could convert this to python and test,  i have partially understood the algorithm that you mentioned,  could you post some link as to what could be the reading list to make it better.

Comment: Also what could be the best approach to recognize the "ataul karim" Written inside the boxes.  I have a character recognition model working at 95% trained on freely available data and I have a sentence and words recognition model working at 80%. I fixed of extracting individual element inside box  because I could not remove the entire bounding boxes and treat it as a sentence ,  my attempt https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56558211/detecting-and-removing-vertical-and-horizontal-lines-in-opencv

Comment: I am sorry, but outside of the hough transform, I just made the rest of that stuff up... so I don't know of any reading other than just reading my example code.

Comment: I agree with your approach for character recognition.  After you get the characters isolated in those boxes, it should be completely trivial for any machine learning based model to determine the correct text.  Looking at that other post, I def feel like this is the right direction, ie break it up into sections like this and get the characters one at a time.

Comment: To be clear, my method should work pretty well with most of that page on your other post, but you will likely need to break it up into little chunks like you did in this post in order to optimize your hough lines as just giving hough lines the whole page will cause a mess as you found out :P

Comment: So I looked at (and provided a completely different style of solution) your other post that is kinda your same issue here.  You may have some luck just running ocr on those as words, but I think your more robust solution is going to be making a preliminary algorythm that breaks up that bigger picture into single lines of boxes like seen in this post, and then running something like this on them and isolating the individual chars as it will be incredibly precise and accurate.