# remove small whits dots from binary image using opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, image-preprocessing

i have a binary image and I want to remove small white dots from the image using opencv python.You can refer to my problem here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57282827/use-cv2-connectedcomponentswithstats-to-display-images)

My original image is

[image]

i want the output image as:

[image]

Comment: What code have you tried? Please read this forum's help section for how to ask a good question.

Comment: @fmw42 I have shared the link of the code which i tried .please refer it

Comment: Sorry, I missed it. But why did you not just modify the one post?

Comment: the function connectedcomponentswithstats is working but i am unable to display in in form of image

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42798659/how-to-remove-small-connected-objects-using-opencv

Comment: See also https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/31/detecting-multiple-bright-spots-in-an-image-with-python-and-opencv/

Answer (score 14):

This seems to work using connected components in Python Opencv.

[image]

```
#!/bin/python3.7

import cv2
import numpy as np

src = cv2.imread('img.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# convert to binary by thresholding
ret, binary_map = cv2.threshold(src,127,255,0)

# do connected components processing
nlabels, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(binary_map, None, None, None, 8, cv2.CV_32S)

#get CC_STAT_AREA component as stats[label, COLUMN] 
areas = stats[1:,cv2.CC_STAT_AREA]

result = np.zeros((labels.shape), np.uint8)

for i in range(0, nlabels - 1):
    if areas[i] >= 100:   #keep
        result[labels == i + 1] = 255

cv2.imshow("Binary", binary_map)
cv2.imshow("Result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

cv2.imwrite("Filterd_result.png, result)
```

[image]

See [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/212171/image-pre-processing-and-segmentation)

Comment: Can you help me to apply this to multiple jpg images and save it with the same name but extension png?

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use image smoothing techniques like gaussian blur, etc. to remove noise from the image, followed by binary thresholding like below:

```
img = cv2.imread("your-image.png",0)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(13,13),0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

cv2.imshow('original', img)
cv2.imshow('output', thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWinsdows()
```

output:

[image]

Read about different image smoothing/blurring techniques from [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but using gaussian blur the edges would be affected so I want connectedcompoments function to work

Comment: But there are also image blurring techniques which preserves the edges while removing noises like median blur, etc. So, why not you try those.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `closing` function - erosion followed by dilation. It don't need the blurring function.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

img = cv.imread('original',0)
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)

opening = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

cv2.imshow('original', img)
cv2.imshow('output', opening)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You mean `opening`. (I would edit, but the queue is full...)